# Use of article in front of product names

Tags: articles

In English, a definite article is not typically used in front of company names, except if you want to refer to some particular building (e.g. *I went to the McDonald's around the corner*).

However, does the same thing hold for product names? For example, which of the following sentences would work better?

1. Logitech's new S30 is an improved version of the S29.
2. Logitech's new S30 is an improved version of S29.

The former sounds much better to me, but that may be because we throw around a lot of definite articles in my native language :)

Comment: Related: [Why do I want to say “the iPhone” instead of just “iPhone”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/55351/why-do-i-want-to-say-the-iphone-instead-of-just-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

Oddly, I think that there are legal versions of your McDonalds sentence without the article.

- I went to McDonalds just around the corner.
- I went to McDonalds inside the mall.
- I went to McDonalds while I was shopping.

But certainly sentence #2 is ungrammatical.  You need a determiner of *some* sort there.

- Logitech’s new S30 is an improved version of their old S29.
- Logitech’s new S30 is an improved version of that old S29.

However, you can avoid this by using *S29* as an attributive noun:

- Logitech’s new S30 is an improved S29 revision.

Which is a lot like a properly possessive-case rendering:

- Logitech’s new S30 is the S29’s improved version.

Comment: A few notes: Your second McDonalds is spelled wrong. Also, do you mean "just around the **corner**"? I'd tried to submit an edit suggestion, but it was too short and the system wouldn't let me.

Comment: You didn't mention that he **doesn't** need an apostrophe in his example:)

Comment: @Noah, Wait...are you saying there is no apostrophe in McDonald's? There most certainly is: http://www.mcdonalds.com/us/en/contact_us.html

Comment: @JLG- then he definitely needs one.

Answer (score 3):

Between the two examples, definitely #1.

Or, *"Logitech's new S30 is an improved version of **their** S29."*