# Is 'the' necessary when a noun is explained in a same sentence?

Tags: articles

I know that definite article is used when a noun is already known in the context.

But I'm not sure with the usage of definite article when I described something explicitly but it hasn't been mentioned before.

So here's my example.

'I believe children are used to listening to the type of music that celebrities promote their life styles'

In the sentence, 'the type of music' was not mentioned before, however I described what type of music it is in the sentence. Also it sounds more comfortable with the article.

Is the article used right? or should it be just 'a type of music'?

Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: The article is fine, and no article would be wrong. That said, just like with your previous question, the sentence as a whole is ungrammatical and does not make sense.

Comment: @RegDwigнt thanks for pointing that out. I had to make up the sentence to support my question but obviously I didn't do it very well.

Comment: But my question is, having article is fine because it is described later?

Comment: Say, 'I have an example that might help you understand when to use definite article correctly'. In the sentence I believe it is correct to use indefinite article. But also 'an example' was explained later followed by 'that'.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155879/the-definite-article-in-front-of-a-noun-that-is-followed-by-a-defining-clause?rq=1
I read the question and it was explained in the answer. However it still did not scratch my brain enough to fully get it. The author of the question also commented on the second answer asking the explained object is also a definite group (in my previous comment, 'an example' is a subset of all other examples and hence it is unique).